# How to make visible or display Zoom control buttons always in android application?

Tags: android, zooming, pinchzoom

How to make visible this Zoom Control buttons in my app without disappearing? if this zoomcontrol button is visible then user don't want to get confused about zooming. When I try to scroll or zoom in then only this zoom control button appears. If I don't try to pinch zoom also this zoom control button should be appear in my app. How can i do this. Any ideas?

Note: I am using Webview contents and Android 2.2 version.

This is my code:

```
  WebView wv =new WebView(MainActivity.this); 
  wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
```